# Denial of service when uploading a file

Tags: web-application

Is a DOS attack possible when uploading a big file.

Lets say a website has a file upload control, and there is an attempt to upload a file of  1 GB size.

If the connection remains open for a long time, does it mean that system resources are being consumed?
Is it possible to upload a lot of big files that way? or does the process simply "hang"? connection is open, but nothing is being uploaded?

How can you check the size of a file before attempting to upload it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone can upload a large file to your site, then they can presumably establish many sessions to your site and perform large file uploads on all of them.

This will consume disk space on your server; it will consume network bandwidth; and it will consume TCP sockets.  This is effectively a denial of service.

Even if your file upload control checks the file size before uploading (which it should), this won't protect you from attackers who can bypass the check.  You will also want to monitor resource consumption on your server, and if the upload takes too long or the uploaded data gets too large, you might want to terminate the connection.

Comment: Thats what I have been thinking.. So if the connection remains hanging for a few hours..it is resource consuming

Answer (score 1):

A single file upload should not effect performance if the server is set up correctly. Generally speaking, download speeds are faster than upload speeds, and this is especially true with home connections. You will much more likely reach your bandwidth cap before the server does, making this a very poor denial of service attack.

Web servers are multi-threaded and will not block new connections because you already have one open. There are some limitations on certain browsers due to the number of worker processes spawned, and the amount of memory these processes use.

If you add more than one client to the equation, it becomes a Distributed DOS and is much more feasible. The idea of uploading content in a DDOS is still inefficient. When DDOSing, you often times look for a force multiplier built into the protocol. This is where you send a small amount of data, and the server sends back a much larger reply. This can be seen with DNS Amplification Attacks, where its possible to reach a 1:70 ratio of client:server data.

All operating systems have methods of determining file size, please refer to the documentation that came with your OS.

Comment: I should note that the DNS amplification attack is an attempt to saturate the servers bandwidth, denying services to other users. This isn't the only type of DDOS, and with regard to file upload, it may be possible(and easier) to saturate the servers disk IO also.